# Bluetooth earbuds disconnects seconds after connecting

Tags: bluetooth

I can't properly connect my Sennheiser Momentum True Wireless 2 earbuds with my Ubuntu laptop.
I use ubuntu version 18.04.4 LTS.
When I try to connect using bluetoothctl I get this.

```
[NEW] Device 00:1B:66:B8:E9:EA MOMENTUM TW 2

[bluetooth]# info 00:1B:66:B8:E9:EA 
Device 00:1B:66:B8:E9:EA (public)
    Name: MOMENTUM TW 2
    Alias: MOMENTUM TW 2
    Paired: no
    Trusted: no
    Blocked: no
    Connected: no
    LegacyPairing: no
    UUID: Device Information        (0000180a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Battery Service           (0000180f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Unknown                   (0000fdce-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)

[bluetooth]# trust 00:1B:66:B8:E9:EA 
[CHG] Device 00:1B:66:B8:E9:EA Trusted: yes
Changing 00:1B:66:B8:E9:EA trust succeeded

[bluetooth]# pair 00:1B:66:B8:E9:EA 
Attempting to pair with 00:1B:66:B8:E9:EA
[CHG] Device 00:1B:66:B8:E9:EA Connected: yes
[CHG] Device 00:1B:66:B8:E9:EA Modalias: usb:v1377p7001d0460
[CHG] Device 00:1B:66:B8:E9:EA UUIDs: 00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device 00:1B:66:B8:E9:EA UUIDs: 00001108-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device 00:1B:66:B8:E9:EA UUIDs: 0000110a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device 00:1B:66:B8:E9:EA UUIDs: 0000110b-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device 00:1B:66:B8:E9:EA UUIDs: 0000110c-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device 00:1B:66:B8:E9:EA UUIDs: 0000110e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device 00:1B:66:B8:E9:EA UUIDs: 0000111e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device 00:1B:66:B8:E9:EA UUIDs: 00001200-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device 00:1B:66:B8:E9:EA UUIDs: 0000eb03-d102-11e1-9b23-00025b00a5a5
[CHG] Device 00:1B:66:B8:E9:EA ServicesResolved: yes
[CHG] Device 00:1B:66:B8:E9:EA Paired: yes
Pairing successful
[CHG] Device 00:1B:66:B8:E9:EA ServicesResolved: no
[CHG] Device 00:1B:66:B8:E9:EA Connected: no

[bluetooth]# connect 00:1B:66:B8:E9:EA 
Attempting to connect to 00:1B:66:B8:E9:EA
[CHG] Device 00:1B:66:B8:E9:EA Connected: yes
"Here it makes a buzzing noise for a second"
Connection successful
[CHG] Device 00:1B:66:B8:E9:EA Connected: no
[CHG] Device 00:1B:66:B8:E9:EA Class: 0x00240404
[CHG] Device 00:1B:66:B8:E9:EA Icon: audio-card
[CHG] Device 00:1B:66:B8:E9:EA Connected: yes
[CHG] Device 00:1B:66:B8:E9:EA Connected: no
[CHG] Device 00:1B:66:B8:E9:EA Connected: yes
[CHG] Device 00:1B:66:B8:E9:EA Connected: no

[bluetooth]# info 00:1B:66:B8:E9:EA 
Device 00:1B:66:B8:E9:EA (public)
    Name: MOMENTUM TW 2
    Alias: MOMENTUM TW 2
    Class: 0x00240404
    Icon: audio-card
    Paired: yes
    Trusted: yes
    Blocked: no
    Connected: no
    LegacyPairing: no
    UUID: Serial Port               (00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Headset                   (00001108-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Audio Source              (0000110a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Audio Sink                (0000110b-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: A/V Remote Control Target (0000110c-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: A/V Remote Control        (0000110e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Handsfree                 (0000111e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: PnP Information           (00001200-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Vendor specific           (0000eb03-d102-11e1-9b23-00025b00a5a5)
    Modalias: usb:v1377p7001d0460
[bluetooth]#
```

I already have pulseaudio installed and restarting it doesn't seem to help. I also have windows on my laptop and the earbuds work fine there.

Comment: To start with, which release number of Ubuntu is installed?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]